# Can't access $location when using .controller method in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, firebase, angularfire

I'm using ng-submit on a form to push data to a Firebase, everything works as expected. What I would like to do is change views at the same time. On the submit button itself I have ng-click set to execute a function using $location. If I place my changeView function in a .controller method I can't utilize $location (specifically, it says - "Error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$location.path')"). Any help would be super duper.

```
// This doesn't work and throws the error
myApp.controller('CtrlName', ['$scope', 'angularFireCollection',
    function($scope, angularFireCollection, $location) {

         $scope.changeView = function(view) {
             $location.path(view);
         }

    }
]);



// This works as expected, but I'm name spacing my functions globally and I will have to change how I'm accessing my Firebase, which isn't really desired.   
function CtrlName($scope, angularFireCollection, $location) {

    $scope.changeView = function(view) {
        $location.path(view);
    }

}
```

Here is my template:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="tactics.add(tactic)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Method</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="tactic.type">
                <option>Email</option>
                <option>Display</option>
            <option>SMS</option>
            <option>Print</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="changeView('/my-tactics')">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Looking at this post two years later I can't believe I was doing this. For anyone crawling SO, don't do this. This is what promises are for. What I should have been doing was firing a function that manipulated the data and once complete then perform the proper redirect. This can be done with $http, $q, or even Firebase's $save().

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're not injecting the `$location` object into your controller. It's listed in your function parameters but you forgot to add it to the list before said function.

```
myApp.controller('CtrlName', ['$scope', 'angularFireCollection','$location',
    function($scope, angularFireCollection, $location) {
        ...
    }]);
```

Comment: Dude, I swear I tried that, but now it is working. Thanks. Although this is now killing my form submit. Your answer is correct so I will mark as such, but I think the best way to execute this is to get away from having two separate events. Refactoring...

Comment: Glad I could help.  Your other problem might be attributed to you using `ng-submit` in your form tag but the `ng-click` in the submit button is taking "precedence" because its actually changing your URL path.  It might not be taking precedence but its definitely changing your URL/view either before or right after your form submit.

Answer (score 4):

Also do not forget to add $location into your action:

```
authControllers.controller('AuthRegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',

function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.save = function (user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/angular/auth/register',
            data: user
        }).success(function (d) {
             $location.path('/login');

        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Note: Be sure to add '$location' on the first line and $location on the third line.

Spent about 15 minutes because I missed it on the third line:
function ($scope, $http, $location) {

Answer (score 1):

Holy cow I can't believe I was ever doing this. #Facepalm. Here is the proper way to redirect on a form submission.

**Template**

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="vm.submit(tactic)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Method</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="tactic.type">
                <option>Email</option>
                <option>Display</option>
            <option>SMS</option>
            <option>Print</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('CtrlName', function($scope, $location, $log, angularFireCollection, tactics) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.submit = function submit(item) {

    tactics.add(item)
      .then(function(rsp) {
        $log.debug('Attempted to add tactic to Firebase', rsp);
        $location.path('/my-tactics');
      });

  };

  }
);
```

*Notable Changes:*

1. I'm not using annotations for my DI, I offload this to ng-annotate, which then mitigates any issues like the one I ran into when originally asking this question.
2. I'm using 'controller as' syntax which didn't exist at the time of this question.
3. I'm no longer creating some weird race condition by trying to execute two separate actions in two separate functions on possibly one event. Promises are a perfect solution for this sort of action.